# Object Reverse Action Script 3.0

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, object, foreach, foreach-loop-container

When i try to print the object, it simply print in reverse.

Code:

```
var marcos:Object = new Object();

marcos.nome = "Marcos";
marcos.ano = 19;

for (var prop in marcos)
{
trace(prop + ":" + " " + marcos[prop]);
}
```

Output:

ano: 19
nome: Marcos

I had search in the adobe documentation about object and for each but nothing seems ot explain that.
When i try to put more elements the object simply get randomic orders, i really dont know what's going on, if someone could help me i would be grateful.

Answer (score 2):

That's just the way it works with a `for in` loop and a non-array Object. It's [documented on the Adobe website](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7fcf.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f5b):

> The for..in loop iterates through the properties of an object, or the elements of an array. For example, you can use a for..in loop to iterate through the properties of a generic object (object properties are not kept in any particular order, so properties may appear in a seemingly random order).